# req.user gets changed to Array object

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, compoundjs

I'm facing a weird issue after I ran `npm install`.

The instance of `req.user` when accessing in `requireManager() (or any controller) is of type Array rather then the object returned from passport.deserializeUser.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    compound.models.User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
         done(err, user);
    });
});
```

console.log(req.user.constructor)  in controller prints

```
function Array() { [native code] }
```

and

```
console.log(user.constructor)  in `passport.deserializeUser` prints:


 function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
        if (!(this instanceof model))
          return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
        Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
    }
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: Can you post your (de)serializeUser implementations?

Comment: Edited the post and included deserializeUser

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with CompoundJS, but could it be overwriting `req.user` itself? Your `deserializeUser` looks okay.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone ends up here from a Google search (like me).

In `passport.deserializeUser`, using `findById` on a model returns an array, either use `findOne` or pass `user[0]` to `done`.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    myModel.findOne(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this myself but decided to search for perhaps a more "legit" answer. Had no idea that findById returned an array, but this explains it the weird behavior.